# jInstagram - How to establish connection?

Tags: java, api, instagram

I want to build an app in Java based on live showing certain photos of Instagram tagged with a particular hashtag. I'm currently trying to use jInstagram, but I can't understand the flow of the API Instagram. It's not like the Twitter API. Instagram API seems to call for a server in the middle of my app and their servers, while Twitter API gave me access to the gardenhose without a lot of work. And, overall, thanks to the nice samples on Twitter4J.org

I'd be grateful if somebody can help me to start with. I just want to get live photos with certain hashtag of Instagram but I don't know if I'd should set up a server or where they give me an access token.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to register your app to instagram's website and get your `apiKey` and `apiSecret`. Then you can choose a callback URL and a scope.

```
InstagramService service = new InstagramAuthService()
                .apiKey("e607b7XXXce54e729bXXXXf40162")
                .apiSecret("651cXXX2ab348a3XXXXa7ae90c6d")
                .callback("http://www.cagdasalagoz.com")
                .scope("basic public_content likes comments follower_list relationships")
                .build();
```

After this, you can get the authorization like this.

```
    String authorizationUrl = service.getAuthorizationUrl();

    System.out.println(authorizationUrl); //paste in browser

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Paste the code gotten in the browser (at the end of the URL):  ");
    String verCode = sc.nextLine();  //SCAN VERIFIER CODE

    Verifier verifier = new Verifier(verCode);

    Token accessToken = service.getAccessToken(verifier);  //Token successfully gotten

    //** RUNS OK UP TO THIS LINE INCLUDED **//
    Instagram instagram = new Instagram(accessToken);   //Ok
```

About getting the posts by a tag can be achived by this method I guess.

```
String tag="seaside";
instagram.getRecentMediaFeedTags(tag);
```

You can learn more about jInstagram from [this page](https://github.com/sachin-handiekar/jInstagram/wiki/jInstagram-Usage#service-object).